# How can i reduce the memory usage in this code?

Tags: c++

The complete question is here https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/random-attendance/ . Please let me know if I'm not allowed to ask these questions here.
I think my solution is correct and I am getting expected result for the examples provided in question but getting memory exceeded error.

```
bool compare (string a, string b){
    return lexicographical_compare(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
}

vector<int> Solution::solve(int A, vector<int> &B) {
    vector <string> x;
    for(int i=0; i<A; i++){
        x.push_back(to_string(i+1));
    }
    sort(x.begin(), x.end(), compare);
    vector <int> ans;
    for(int i=0; i<B.size(); i++){
        ans.push_back(stoi(x[B[i]-1]));
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: The question states that you can have up to 1000000000 items.  Your solution does not take this in consideration.  Thus you probably need to come up with a solution, probably totally different, than the one you came up with.  Also, these online coding sites many times have questions where the naive solution does not work for large inputs, either in time complexity, space complexity, or both.  Those questions are there to test whether *you* can figure out the non-naive methods.  Trying to tweak naive solutions almost never works.

Comment: Do you really need the `vector<string>` (and to sort it, not to mention all the conversions)? If I understand correctly, it contains "1", then "10" to "19" (10 values), then "100" to "199" (100 values) and so on, up to A. It shouldn't be too difficult to find a formula that, given an index, outputs the correct value.

Comment: @Bob__: `1, 10, 100, 101, .., 109, 11, 110, ...`

Comment: `std::string` already uses lexicographic order, so you don't have to implement it. And your version does extra copy Btw.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, my bad.It *is* more difficult than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just write the function that converts B[i] into the correct value given A, possibly using additional preprocessed data derived from A that will speed up/simplify the computation. The preprocessed data should be about (log_10 A) integers, i.e., at most 10 or 20 integers. Not surely not A stings.

The solution you proposed fails miserably when A is very big, yet it is possible to write code that runs at O(B) for any A (as long as A is an int or long long, the actual speed should probably be O(B log log A) for arbitrarily large A).

---

As a hint I will give you an example. Say A = 392,908.

And we have some B[0] and we want to determine its index.

What is the first digit? Is it 1 or 2? May be it is 3 or 4? How can one tell.

In fact there are exactly 111,111 indices that start with 1 and same with 2, while there are 11,111 incides that start with 4 (same with 5,6,7,8,9).

While the remaining amount (A - 2*111,111+6*11,111) is for number 3. Using this info it is not hard to determine the first digit in the index of B[0].

Rest can be determined via a similar procedure.